# What's the probability to select n numbers from $n^3$ different numbers(repetition is allowed) so that they are all unique?

Tags: probability

Randomly select *n* numbers from range $[1, n^3]$(repetition is allowed), what's the probability that all *n* numbers are unique?

According to *Introduction to Algorithm*, it's at least $1-1/n$. I can make up the probability, but I don't understand it quite well. Here is the way I get the probability

$P(n\space unique\space numbers) = 1-P(there's\space a\space repetition)=1-C(n, 2)1/n^3≥1-1/n$

Is it right? In fact I don't understand why I'd make $P(there's\space a\space repetition)=C(n,2)1/n^3$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear to me why you can say that the probability of a repetition is ${n\choose 2}$. Here's another way to think about the problem:

If the $n$ numbers must be distinct, then there are $n^3$ choices for the first number, $n^3-1$ choices for the second number, and so on, up to $n^3-(n-1)$ choices for the $n$th number.

Therefore the probability that all $n$ numbers are distinct is
$$ \frac{n^3}{n^3}\frac{n^3-1}{n^3}\cdots\frac{n^3-n+1}{n^3}=\Big(1-\frac{1}{n^3}\Big)\Big(1-\frac{2}{n^3}\Big)\cdots\Big(1-\frac{n-1}{n^3}\Big)$$
$$ \geq\Big(1-\frac{n-1}{n^3}\Big)^{n-1}\geq 1-\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^3}>1-\frac{n^2}{n^3}=1-\frac{1}{n}$$

The second inequality in the second line is [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality).